# Can this merge sort be more efficient?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, mergesort

I made a merge sort in python just to get a better understanding of how it works.  The code works fine, but I'm wondering if anyone can critique what I've written.  Can this be more efficient?
I anticipate that there is some room for improvement in my recursion - the function continues running after it calls and runs itself.  I've prevented it from continuing unnecessarily by simply giving it a return immediately after a recursive call, but I am not sure if there is a better method.

Also, I have to specify in the output that I want index 0 of the returned value, as the merging section of the function generates a multidimensional array.

```
"""
2019-10-17

This project simply re-creates common sorting algorithms
for the purpose of becoming more intimately familiar with 
them.
"""

import random
import math

#Generate random array
array = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(random.randint(5, 100))]
print(array)

#Merge Sort
def merge(array, split = True):
    split_array = []
    #When the function is recursively called by the merging section, the split will be skipped
    continue_splitting = False
    if split == True:
        #Split the array in half
        for each in array:
            if len(each) > 1:
                split_array.append(each[:len(each)//2])
                split_array.append(each[len(each)//2:])
                continue_splitting = True
            else:
                split_array.append(each)
    if continue_splitting == True:
        sorted_array = merge(split_array)
        #A return is set here to prevent the recursion from proceeding once the array is properly sorted
        return sorted_array
    else:
        sorted_array = []
        if len(array) != 1:
            #Merge the array
            for i in range(0, len(array), 2):
                #Pointers are used to check each element of the two mergin arrays
                pointer_a = 0
                pointer_b = 0
                #The temp array is used to prevent the sorted array from being corrupted by the sorting loop
                temp = []
                if i < len(array) - 1:
                    #Loop to merge the array
                    while pointer_a < len(array[i]) or pointer_b < len(array[i+1]):
                        if pointer_a < len(array[i]) and pointer_b < len(array[i+1]):
                            if array[i][pointer_a] <= array[i + 1][pointer_b]:
                                temp.append(array[i][pointer_a])
                                pointer_a += 1
                            elif array[i + 1][pointer_b] < array[i][pointer_a]:
                                temp.append(array[i + 1][pointer_b])
                                pointer_b += 1
                        #If the pointer is equal to the length of the sub array, the other sub array will just be added fully
                        elif pointer_a < len(array[i]):
                            for x in range(pointer_a, len(array[i])):
                                temp.append(array[i][x])
                                pointer_a += 1
                        elif pointer_b < len(array[i + 1]):
                            for x in range(pointer_b, len(array[i + 1])):
                                temp.append(array[i + 1][x])
                                pointer_b += 1
                else:
                    for each in array[i]:
                        temp.append(each)
                sorted_array.append(temp)
            if len(sorted_array) != 1:
                #Recursively sort the sub arrays
                sorted_array = merge(sorted_array, False)
    return sorted_array


sorted_array = merge([array])[0]
print()
print(sorted_array)
```

Comment: There is a separate site for review of working code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Stackoverflow is mainly for code with problems. But you may get comments here also.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in code review

Comment: A one time allocation of the temporary array and then alternating the direction of merge for each level of recursion (top down) or pass (bottom up) would be faster. My experience is a merge sort in Python is about 50 times slower than a merge sort in C/C++ (with essentially the same code).

Answer (score 0):

To make it more efficient, you simply can use `sum()` and `sorted()` to merge and sort the lists:

```py
list1 = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11]]
list2 = [[2, 7, 10], [0, 4, 6], [3, 11, 1]]
list3 = [[10, 567, 34], [-10, -30, -109], [98, 10001, 5]]

def merge_sort(lists, ascending=True):

    if ascending == True: # If in an ascending order
        return sorted(sum(lists,[])) # `sum()` merges and `sorted()` sorts it

    elif ascending == False: # If in a descending order
        return sorted(sum(lists,[]), reverse=True) # `reverse=True` makes it descending
```

```py
>>> print(merge_sort(list1))
    print(merge_sort(list2))
    print(merge_sort(list3))

[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11]
[-109, -30, -10, 5, 10, 34, 98, 567, 10001]
```

```py
>>> print(merge_sort(list1, ascending=False))
    print(merge_sort(list2, ascending=False))
    print(merge_sort(list3, ascending=False))

[11, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 0]
[11, 10, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[10001, 567, 98, 34, 10, 5, -10, -30, -109]
```